# about a indexable type (index signature) in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make a generic Dictionary like Dictionary of c#.

but javascript not support bracket([]) operator overloading.

so i think of a trick. that's just using index signature.

but it has a critical problem. cannot traverse elements like c#. (for or foreach)

help me!

ps. sorry to english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either go with a plain object:

```
 const dict: { [key: string]: number } = {};

 dict["a"] = 1;
 dict["b"] = 2;

 for(let key in dict)
   console.log(key + ":" + dict[key]);

for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(dict))
  consope.log(k + ":" + v);
```

Or you use a Map:

```
  const dict = new Map<string, number>();

  dict.set("a", 1).set("b", 2);

  for(const [k, v] of dict.entries())
    console.log(k + ":" + v);
```